# How to read PDF file and display it on JTextPane?

Tags: java, netbeans

I want to do a program that can choose a `PDF file` from my computer and later crop in few portions by automatically.

The concept I had first created a `JfileChooser` to select the file I want and display it on `JTextPane`, and then read / determine the structure of PDF file in order to crop in according to the portion I want.

Can I ask how to do it? Any library I can refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) API to manipulate PDF file to your Java program. There is enough documentation there about text extraction for you to follow.

Comment: It's seen useful, have a look first, thanks!

should I download the library or it already provided by netbean?

Comment: You can use netbeans as your IDE to easily include the library.